# What region should I choose to store my app in google cloud platform?

Tags: html, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/How_do_you_host_your_website_on_Google_App_Engine

Step 6 says I have to choose a region to store my application in between 1 and 7. I do not know what the difference is and what that means :) thanks for any help

Comment: different location

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pick a region that is close to your users. If you are in Australia, pick `australia-southeast1` (not `europe-west1`). If you have 2 or more good candidates, look at the [Google Cloud services available by location](https://cloud.google.com/about/locations/#locations).  Not all locations offer the same services. Eliminate any location that doesn't offer a service that you might use in the future. If you still have 2 or more good candidates, flip a coin.